# Cannot Find Infinite Loop

Tags: java, loops, infinite

So I'm trying to write a method where I iterate through a predetermined word in a hangman game. I would like to ultimately go through each character and put an "_" if the letter has not been guessed and show the letter if it has, however, I'm running into an infinite loop and I cannot find where it is. I'm thinking that my logic may be wrong as well.

```
public String hiddenWord() {
    String hiddenWord = "";
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < this.word.length()) {            
        if ( this.word.contains(hiddenWord) ) {
            char c = this.word.charAt(i);
            hiddenWord += c;
        } else {
            hiddenWord += "_";
        }
        i++;
    }

    return hiddenWord;
}
```

Comment: Your observations seem to be inconsistent with the code you pasted above.

Comment: `i` starts at `0` and increases by one every iteration, no matter what. The loop exits when the length of a string (that does not change) is reached. This cannot be an infinite loop.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger? You can execute one line at a time, examine the objects' members and variables and see how the program is behaving the way you wrote it to. For a program as simple as this, debugging it yourself can be a valuable educational exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the logic is:

1. Given a word, like "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis".
2. Guess a character, say 'i'.
3. Return "______________i_______i__i_i____________i__i_".

You can loop through the word char by char, and compare with the guess.

Sample code.

```
public class InfiniteLoop {
    String word;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfiniteLoop il = new InfiniteLoop();
        il.word = "Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis";
        String hw = il.hiddenWord('i');
        System.out.println(hw);
    }

    public String hiddenWord(char g) {
        String hiddenWord = "";
        int i = 0;

        while ( i < this.word.length()) {            
            if ( this.word.charAt(i) == g) {
                hiddenWord += g;
            } else {
                hiddenWord += "_";
            }
            i++;
        }

        return hiddenWord;
    }
}
```